# gcc compiler optimizations affected code

Tags: c++, gcc

Unfortunately I am not working with open code right now, so please consider this a question of pure theoretical nature. 
The C++ project I am working with seems to be definitely crippled by the following options and at least GCC 4.3 - 4.8 are causing the same problems, didn't notice any trouble with 3.x series (these options might have not been existed or worked differently there), affected are the platforms Linux x86 and Linux ARM. The options itself are automatically set with O1 or O2 level, so I had to find out first what options are causing it:

tree-dominator-opts

tree-dse

tree-fre

tree-pre

gcse

cse-follow-jumps

Its not my own code, but I have to maintain it, so how could I possibly find the sources of the trouble these options are making. Once I disabled the optimizations above with "-fno" the code works. 
On a side note, the project does work flawlessly with Visual Studio 2008,2010 and 2013 without any noticeable problems or specific compiler options. Granted, the code is not 100% cross platform, so some parts are Windows/Linux specific but even then I'd like to know what's happening here.
It's no vital question, since I can make the code run flawlessly, but I am still interested how to track down such problems.

So to make it short: How to identify and find the affected code?

I doubt it's a giant GCC bug and maybe there is not even a real fix for the code I am working with, but it's of real interest for me.
I take it that most of these options are eliminations of some kind and I also read the explanations for these, still I have no idea how I would start here.

Comment: Can you isolate a specific code location where the issue occurs, like  a specific function which returns an unexpected value when optimization is enabled? Then, you can compare the assembly code generated in either case (use `gcc -S`) to see what different instructions the compiler generates. In any case, it would help if you could create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) which reproduces the issue, so that we can verify it (even if your code is closed, you could shrink it down to one function which shows the issue)

Comment: *How* doesn't your code work? Does it start to crash? Does it perform badly? Does it produce unexpected results? You *do* build with lots of warnings enabled, and have fixed all warnings properly (not just cast away some things for example)? You're sure there's no bugs or undefined behaviors in your code? Have you checked the generated assembly and compared it to the assembly generated without the optimizations? Maybe it's not really these optimizations specifically, but in combination with some other optimization that causes the problem?

Comment: Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I hit myself on the head…  So, stop using optimizations that pessimize your code.  Until you've identified the bug and reported it to the GCC maintainers and they've fixed it, don't use what doesn't work.  But I think Joachim has an important point — are you sure that the code is squeaky clean with no undefined behaviour anywhere?

Comment: Oh, and blindly using `-O3` have been known to cause problem with some code, either generating faulty code or generating *slower* code than `-O2`. The `-O2` option is generally considered a safe option, if you need more optimization then it might be better to manually *enable* the specific optimizations wanted.

Comment: If the program output is affected by optimization level, it usually means that the code depends on undefined behavior. MSVC and GCC perform optimizations differently, and MSVC might not have been affected by the potential UB. Try other compilers and see if it works for them.

Comment: There were a few bugs up until 4.8 with dce and cse.

Comment: I can't identify the location exactly where it happens. Although I can pinpoint it to some degree there are still hundreds of lines of code in question.Therefor my question about it. The warnings I ruled out pretty much except some reorder and write-strings warnings, so these won't help me here. 
If I knew already what's causing the issue I wouldn't have to ask here. The current optimization level is O2 and I had to compare some ASM already without optimization to even identify the options in question. And no, I am not sure if the code is clean, in fact I doubt it, so I want to find out where.

Comment: for Joachim Pileborg: The code doesn't crash, just some functions don't seem to be executed anymore, I notice that due to replication issues from server to client. So guess can call it unexpected results. I can't notice any significant performance differences with or without though.
for Jonathan Leffler- you are complaining about the pure point of the question, In can't avoid until I know whats going wrong. :)

Comment: oh and to avoid further confusion- the options mentioned above are automatically set with either O1 or O2 and unfortunately not every of these options are specifically noted on the gcc page for these levels, that's why I compared the asm output in the first place to even see what all is set.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: try using debugger. If the program crashes, check the backtrace for places to look for the faulty function. If the program misbehaves (wrong outputs), you should be able to tell where it occurs by carefully placing breakpoints.

If it didn't help and the project is small, you could try compiling a subset of your project with the "-fno" options that stop your program from misbehaving. You could brute-force your way to finding the smallest subset of faulty .cpp files and work your way from there. Note: finding a search algorithm with good complexity could save you a lot of time.

If, by any chance, there is a single faulty .cpp file, then you could further factor its contents into several .cpp files to see which functions are the cause of misbehavior.

Comment: it doesn't crash, "only" misbehave, so I have nothing specifically to use the debugger against and it's a very huge project, so I need a place to start first.

Comment: A good place to start is the place where you first notice the misbehavior. See which function it occurs in, check if its arguments are correct, and if that's the case - the function itself is faulty. If arguments are incorrect, find the function that called it. Rinse and repeat. Assuming that you don't have much global state, in which case - sucks to be you!